# Temporarily disable perforce checkins for myself

Tags: perforce

I have a horrible habit of checking in source files when our group needs to keep the DB stable for a batch of testing.  Is there a way for me to disable checkins for myself and then re-enable when the testing completes?  I still need to use perforce to check out files and monitor the status of the DB.. I just would like to disable my ability to do checkins.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Switch your work into a new branch, and then you can submit without affecting the mainline.

Note that this is somewhat backwards from how it *should* work (the mainline should be branched for stabilization, rather than "freezing" it and forcing everyone *else* to branch) but the principle of "branch on incompatible submit policy" still applies.

https://www.perforce.com/pdf/scm-best-practices.pdf

Comment: A silly alternate solution that only works if you're a command line user: create an alias like `submit = info`.  https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v16.1/cmdref/chapter.introduction.html#introduction.aliases

Answer (score 0):

You could use a read only client: https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/read-only-clients-helix-server-20152